# Permissions for access to Bigquery Project-Id

Tags: google-bigquery, identity-management

When we're working on different projects in bigquery, we're changing project-id from the top panel. We need to get "Bigquery Admin" permission so we can make this choice from above, but we want to keep these permissions to a minimum, so what can we do?

We've discovered this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles), but we don't know which roles are meant to be enough for us. We just don't expect to be able to question the data and keep the query costs on the customer.

Is there a quick way to get this permission? Does the user need to define manual by these roles? Is there a practical way we can get "Bigquery Admin"?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick refresher, in this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#concepts_related_to_access_management):

> **Permissions** determine what operations are **allowed** on a resource.

> A **role** is a **collection of permissions**. You cannot grant a permission to the user directly. Instead, you grant them a role. When you grant a role to a user, you grant them all the permissions that the role contains.

So [Bigquery Admin](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) is already a [**predefined role**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined). You can just assign this role to an authenticated principal to access Bigquery resources on a certain project.